# C#.net- code to display xml file in the datagridview control on button click event

Tags: c#

My xml contains parent thn child then many grandchild.. Each grandchild has many tags with attributes like key and value... I should display the key and value on button click event.how to do it.. Please help me as soon as possible

Comment: I would suggest you to look at `Linq to Xml`.

Comment: We will not write code for you! Try it yourself and then ask questions about what doesn't work.

Comment: As I am new to c#.net I don't know much of it..

Answer (score 0):

are you working with win form /wpf?
try copie /past your xml so.

maybee:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(@"C:\Books\Books.xml");
dataSet.Tables[0].Columns.Remove("useless");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Comment: I tried that. But actually I have to display oly the attribute values of a selected tag not the complete xml file

Comment: you can always remove useless column see code edited. well its for keep it simple but some other way look  better.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private

void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

xmlDoc.Load(xl);

XmlNodeList xnList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("...../.../");

foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)

{

abc = xn.Attributes[

"key"].InnerText;

DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

dataSet.ReadXml(abc);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("name");
    dt.Columns.Add("value");
    XmlDocument Doc = new XmlDocument();
    Doc.Load("example.xml");
    XmlNodeList nodeList = Doc.SelectNodes("/ITEM");
    foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
    {
      foreach (XmlAttribute attr in node.Attributes)
      {
        string name = attr.Name;
        string value = attr.Value;
        DataRow dr = new DataRow();
        dr["name"] = name;
        dr["value"] = value;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
      }          
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
```

Comment: Edited Answer to bind to Gridview

Comment: Err is coming lik type or namespace definition, or end of file expected

Comment: Is inaccessible due to its protection level